# How do I replace part of a text (string) by another in appInventor?

Tags: android, app-inventor

I am using appInventor to develop an app. How do I replace part of a text string by another. This should be pretty straight forward. Had I used Perl,  this is what I will do:

```
$my_str =~ s/abc/xyz/;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

we are talking about **App Inventor**...
you could use the [replace all](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/content/text-blocks.html#replace%20all) block

> **replace all**
>
> Returns a new text string obtained by replacing all occurrences of the
>   substring with the replacement.

[image]

in case this is not what you are looking for, just take a look at the other [text blocks](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/content/text-blocks.html)

Comment: Taifun, thanks. I did look into the text block and the help pages. What I am tying to do is to replace a **regular expression** by a string. This does not work in 'replace all' block (I have tried). Specifically, I am trying to get rid of all the XML tags (<something>) from a text. Is there any other way to do it in appInventor?

Comment: there are only the text blocks, but you also can combine them... that's all... however you can also use HTML/JavaScript, [see examples here](http://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php) and concerning XML you can write your own procedures,  [see this example](http://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php) or use again HTML/JavaScript...

Comment: App Inventor does not have a regular expression replace.  It is now open source, however, so anyone can write one.  :-)

Comment: thank you @espertus (I just have seen in your profile, you are the real AI expert)! The App Inventor sources you can find here http://appinventor.mit.edu/appinventor-sources

Comment: @Taifun, you've been beating me to the App Inventor questions here and giving better answers than I would have.  I appreciate your great work.